# R Assigning multiple classes if value fall between ranges in a vector (Simple way)

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I'm trying to assign a class to values if they are in a certain range. Here is an example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

fieldArea = tibble(TotalFieldArea= runif(100000) * 1000)

fieldArea %<>%
  mutate(Segment2019 = if_else(TotalFieldArea < 99, "Very_Small",
                       if_else(TotalFieldArea < 199, "Small",
                       if_else(TotalFieldArea < 499, "Medium",
                       if_else(TotalFieldArea < 999, "Large", "Key_Account")))))
```

I just wonder if there is a way of simplifying the code in dplyr with something like:

```
# Designing rules
class_rule = c(0, 99, 199, 499, 999)
classes    = c("Very_Small", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "Key_Account")

# Applying rules - (Imaginary Code)
fieldArea %<>% mutate(Segment2019 = classes %in% TotalFieldArea < class_rule)
```

The classes should be assigned if they fall in the range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `cut`

```
library(dplyr)
fieldArea %>%
       mutate(Segment2019 = cut(TotalFieldArea, breaks = c(class_rule, Inf), 
      labels = classes))
```

Comment: Maybe add the Inf upper bound else this will fail on the current op answer, may also define df as `fieldArea = tibble(TotalFiedlArea= runif(100000) * 1000)`

Comment: Oh sorry, I made a huge typo with TotalFiedlArea, changing it!

Comment: as @Bruno mentioned tibble is recognized but I am getting this error: x argument "breaks" is missing, with no default

Comment: @BatuhanKavlak sorry, a typo, it should be `breaks` instead of `levels`